# How to install VirtualBox on linux even with secure boot - bash script

Tags: linux, bash, virtualbox, kernel-module, uefi

I'we buildt a simple bash script which should be able to install VirtualBox repository and VirtualBox, even on secure boot systems. 
It utilizes my own bash Function Library which is in beta. 
So if you have problems running VirtualBox on a secure boot system this is for you.

P.S. I assume rpmfusion is installed

Comments and help getting this running on other distros and versions would be appreciated.
I will update this script continuously as comments arrive

Comment: Thanks. This will be a bigger problem soon as kernel 4.4.0-20+ is being adopted by Ubuntu 16.04. The script below is for Fedora. Any script for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox 6.0 will install with secure boot.

Answer (score -1):

`#!/bin/bash`

`############################################################################` 
`#                                                                          #`
`#  @author         Øystein "iRock" Jacobsen                                #` 
`#  @email          irock.dev@gmail.com                                     #` 
`#  @title          VirtualBox.sh                                           #` 
`#  @date           06.04.15 - 19.03.17                                     #`
`#  @description    Installs VirtualBox repo and VirtualBox                 #` 
`#                                                                          #` 
`############################################################################`

`# -= SCRIPT VARIABLES =- #` 
 `install=1                                # Install / uninstall ( 1 / -1 ).` 
 `package="VirtualBox-5.1 kernel-devel gcc dkms"      # Packages to install.` 
 `user=`users`` 
 `package_url=""                           # Url to said package.` 
 `archive_version=""                       # Version of archive to download.` 
 `archive=""                               # Archive to dowload and install.` 
 `archive_url=""                           # Url to said archive.` 
 `remove_archive=1                 # Remove archive after install ( 0 / 1 ).` 
 `install_path=""                          # Extraction path.` 
 `icon_path="$install_path/icon.png"        # Path to install icon.`
 `icon_url=""                              # Url to icon.` 
 `debug=1                                  # Debugging.` 
 `log=1            # Logging ( 0 / 1 / 2 ) ( None / File / File & Terminal).` 
 `log_file="$script_path/$script_name.log"       # Log file name ($0.log).`

```
# -= IMPORTING FUNCTIONS =-#
source "`dirname "$0"`/framework/FunctionLibrary.sh"                        # Importing FunctionLibrary.sh


# -= ELEVATING PRIVILEGES =- #
elevate_privileges                                                          # Elevate privileges


# -= CORE VARIABLES =- #
core_variables                                                              # Determines system-variables       


# -= PRE INSTALL =- #
repo_url="http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/$pkg/`echo $distro | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`/virtualbox.repo"   # URL to repo.

# -= INSTALL REPOSITORY =- #                                                                
if [ $pkg == "rpm" ]; then
    install_repo "1" "$repo_url" "https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc"
elif [ $pkg == "deb" ]; then
    install_repo "1" "$repo_url" "https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc" "https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc"
fi


# -= INSTALL =- #
install_pkg "1" $package


# -= POST INSTALL =- #
if [ "`getent group vboxusers`" == "" ]; then                                       # If vboxusers group doesn't exist.
    groupadd vboxusers                                                                  # Create vboxusers group.
fi
usermod -a -G vboxusers "$user"                                                     # Add user to vboxusers.


# BUILD DRIVERS #
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup                                                # Build kernel modules.
#/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup                                                          # Build kernel modules.
#/sbin/rcvboxdrv setup                                                              # Build kernel modules.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#############################################################################
#                                                                           #
#   @author         Øystein "iRock" Jacobsen                                #
#   @email          irock.dev@gmail.com                                     #
#   @title          Function Library                                        #
#   @date           11.06.2016 - ?                                          #
#   @description    A library of often used functions                       #
#                                                                           #
#############################################################################


#################################################
#           -= ELEVATE PRIVILEGES =-            #
# @description: Elevates privileges to root and #
#               runs the calling script again.  #
#################################################
function elevate_privileges {
    #if [ $EUID != 0 ]; then                                                                # If not root
    if [ `whoami` != root ]; then
        if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Elevating privileges to root "; echo; fi
        if [ -t 1 ]; then                                                                   # If run from terminal
            sudo sh "$0" "$@"                                                                   # Elevating to root in terminal
            exit 0
        elif [ `gnome-shell --version | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "." -f1` -le 2 ]; then      # If run from Gnome 1 or 2
            gksudo "$0" "$@"                                                                    # Elevating to root in Gnome 1 or 2
            exit 0
        elif [ `gnome-shell --version | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "." -f1` -ge 3 ]; then      # If Gnome version is 3
            pkexec "$0" "$@"                                                                # Elevating to root in Gnome 3
            exit 0
        else                                                                                # If desktop environment is undetermined
            if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Can't determine desktop environment"; echo "Exiting"; echo; fi
            zenity --error --text="Can't determine desktop environment"
            exit -1
        fi
    fi
}


#################################################
#           -= ENUMERATE DISTRO =-              #
# @description: Determines distribution,        #
#               release, kernel and             #
#               architecture                    #
# @TODO:        Add distro unknown!             #
#################################################
function enumerate_distro {
    if [ $debug == 0 ]; then echo "Determining distro"; fi

    if [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then                                                        # If "linux standard base" is present
        distro=`cat /etc/lsb-release | cut -d " " -f1`
        release=`cat /etc/lsb-release | cut -d " " -f3`
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then                                                   # If Debian based distro
        distro="Debian"  # XXX or Ubuntu??
        release=`cat /etc/debian_version`
    elif [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then                                                   # If redhat based distro
        distro=`cat /etc/redhat-release | cut -d  " " -f1`
        release=`cat /etc/redhat-release | cut -d " " -f3`
    else                                                                                    # Else Install lsb
        if [ `rpm -qa dnf` -ne "" ]; then
            dnf -y install redhat-lsb-core
        elif [ `rpm -qa yum` -ne "" ]; then
            yum -y install redhat
        fi  

        distro=`lsb_release -si`
        release=`lsb_release -sr`
    fi
    #distro=`lsb_release -si`   #`lsb_release -i | cut -d":" -f2 | xargs`                   # Distrobution name (Fedora / Debian / Ubuntu / Kali)
    #release=`lsb_release -sr`  #`rpm -E %distro`                                           # Release number (22 / 8.2 / 15.04 / 2.0)
    kernel=`uname -r | cut -d"." -f1-3`                                                     # Kernel version (4.1.6-200)
    arch=`uname -m`             #$(uname -m | sed 's/x86_//;s/i[3-6]86/32/')                # Architecture (x86_64 / i686)

    # if [ -z "$distro" ] || [ -z "$relese" ] || [ -z #$kernel ] || [ z- "$arch ]; then 
    # echo "echo Could not enumerate distro!"
    # exit -1
    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "$distro $release - $kernel-$arch"; echo; fi
}


#################################################
#       -= DETERMINE PACKAGE ENVIRONMENT =-     #
# @description: Determines which packages and   #
#               packamanager the system uses    #
#################################################
function determin_pkgman {
    if [ -z "$distro" ]; then
        enumerate_distro
    fi

    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Determining package manager"; fi
    case "$distro" in
        Fedora)
            if [ $release -le 21 ]; then
                pkgman="yum"
            elif [ $release -ge 22 ]; then
                pkgman="dnf"
            fi
            pkg="rpm"
            ;;
        Debian)
            pkgman="apt-get"
            pkg="deb"
            ;;
        Ubuntu)
            pkgman="apt-get"
            pkg="deb"
            ;;
        Kali)
            pkgman="apt-get"
            pkg="deb"
            ;;
        Raspbian)
            pkgman="apt-get"
            pkg="deb"
            ;;
    esac


    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "$pkgman / $pkg"; echo; fi
}


#################################################
#           -= ENUMERATE SCRIPT =-              #
# @description: Determines script related info  #
#################################################
function enumerate_script { 
    script_name=`basename "$0" ".sh"`                                                       # Script name
    script_ext=`basename "$0" "$script_name"`                                               # Script extension
    script_path="`dirname "$0"`"                                                            # Script path
}


#################################################
#           -= CORE VARIABLES =-                #
# @description: Determines operating system and #
#               script related variables        #
#################################################
function core_variables {
    enumerate_distro                                                                        # Determine distro, release, kernel and architecture.

    determin_pkgman                                                                         # Determines package-manager.

    enumerate_script                                                                        # Determines script-path, name and extension.
}


#################################################
#           -= GET USER INPUT =-                #
# @description: Get userinput from terminal.    #
#################################################
function read_input {
    read input                                                                              # Reads a line from the terminal.
}


#################################################
#           -= CURRENT DATE =-                  #
# @description: Get userinput from terminal.    #
#################################################
function get_date {
    date +%Y%m%d                                                                            # Writes todays date in YYYYMMDD format.
}


#################################################
#           -= ADD USER =-                      #
# @description: Adds a new user to linux.       #
# @parameters:                                  #
#           $1      username        (string)    #
#           $2-$N   groups          (string)    #
#################################################
function add_user {
    echo "Adding user: $1"
    useradd "$1"                                                                            # Add new user
    passwd "$1"                                                                             # Prompt for password
    for group in "${@:2}"; do                                                               # For all arguments except first
        adduser $group                                                                      # Add user to group
    done
    echo
}


#################################################
#               -= SET HOSTNAME =-              #
# @description: Sets the hostname of the system.#
# @parameters:                                  #
#           $1      hostname        (string)    #
#################################################
function set_hostname {
    echo "Setting hostname: $1"
    temp=`hostname`                                                                         # Find old hostname
    sed -i "s/$temp/$1/" /etc/hostname                                                      # Replacing old hostname with new
    sed -i "s/$temp/$1/" /etc/hosts                                                         # Replacing old hostname in known hosts
    hostname $1                                                                             # Setting hostname for current session
    echo
}

#################################################
#           -= IS PACKAGE INSTALLED =-          #
# @description: Determine if package is         #
#               installed.                      #
# @parameters:                                  #
#           $1      install / remove    (1/0)   #
#           $2      package name                #
#################################################
function is_pkg_installed {
    if [ -z $pkgman ]; then
        determin_pkgman
    fi

    which $2
    if [[ $? == 1 ] && [ $1 == 1 ]]; then
        install_pkg $1 $2
    fi
}


#################################################
#           -= INSTALL PACKAGES =-              #
# @description: Install/Remove packages         #
# @parameters:                                  #
#           $1:     install / remove    (1/0)   #   
#           $2-$N:  packages to handle          #
#################################################
function install_pkg {
    if [ -z $pkgman ]; then
        determin_pkgman
    fi


    if [ $1 == 1 ]; then
        if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Installing ${@:2} with $pkgman"; fi
        $pkgman -y install "${@:2}"
    elif [ $1 == 0 ]; then
        if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Removing ${@:2} with $pkgman"; fi
        $pkgman -y remove "${@:2}"
    fi

    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo; fi
}


#################################################
#           -= INSTALL ARCHIVE =-               #
# @description: Install\Remove archive          #
# @parameters:                                  #
#           $1:     install / remove    (1/0)   #
#           $2:     install path        (string)#
#           $3:     url to archive      (string)#
#################################################
function install_arch {     
    if [ $1 == 1 ]; then
        if [ ! -e `basename "$3"` ]; then               
            if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Downloading $3"; fi  
            wget "$3"
            echo
        fi
        if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Installing `basename "$3"` to $2"; fi
        if [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
            mkdir "$2"
        fi
        tar -xf `basename "$3"` -C "$2"
        if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Deleting `basename "$3"`"; fi
        rm `basename "$3"`
    elif [ $1 == 0 ]; then
        if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "Deleting $2"; fi
        rm -rf "$2"
    fi

    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo; fi
}


#################################################
#           -= INSTALL IMAGE =-                 #
# @description: Install an image to a device.   #
# @parameters:                                  #   
#           $1      image_path      (string)    #
#           $2      install_device  (string)    #
#################################################
function install_image {
    echo "Installing $1 to $2"
    if [ -e $1 ]; then
        if [ -e "/dev/$2" ]; then
            echo "Unmounting:"                                          # Unmount all partitions device
            df -h | grep "$2"
            df -h | grep "2" | cut -d' ' -f1 | while read line ; do umount $line ; done
            echo
            echo "Installing:"
            dd bs=4M if="$1" of="/dev/$2"                               # Install image to device
            sync                                                        # Flush cache 
            echo "Done"
        else
            echo "Could not find $2"
        fi
    else
        echo "Could not find image $1"
    fi
    echo
}


#################################################
#           -= INSTALL REPOSITORY =-            #
# @description: Install/Remove repository       #
# @parameters:                                  #
#           $1:     install / remove    (1/0)   #
#           $2:     repository package url      #
#           $3-$N:  repository gpg key url      #
# @TODO:    Add apt-get repo download           #
#################################################   
function install_repo {
    if [ -z $pkgman ]; then
        determin_pkgman
    fi

    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "`date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M` - Installing $2"; fi

    repo_ext=`basename "$2" | awk -F "." '{print $NF}'`         # Repository extension
    repo_name=`basename "$2" ".$repo_ext"`                      # Repository name

    if [ $pkgman == "yum" ] && [ "$repo_ext" == "rpm" ]; then
        $pkgman config-manager --add-repo "$2"
    elif [ $pkgman == "yum" ] && [ "$repo_ext" == "repo" ]; then
        rpm --import -f $2
    elif [ $pkgman == "dnf" ] && [ "$repo_ext" == "rpm" ]; then
        $pkgman -y install "$2"
    elif [ $pkgman == "dnf" ] && [ "$repo_ext" == "repo" ]; then
        curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/"$repo_name.$repo_ext" $2
    fi

    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo "`date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M` - Adding repository gpg keys ${@:3}"; fi
    if [ $pkg == "rpm" ]; then
        for url in ${@:3} ; do
            rpm --import "$url"
        done
    elif [ $pkg == "deb" ]; then
        for url in ${@:3} ; do
            wget -q "$url" -O- | apt-key add -
        done
    fi

    if [ $debug != 0 ]; then echo; fi
}
```